# ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework cant access id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having trouble with identity framework.

I have built a database called `ukcustomers` which I access using Entity Framework, and it has an `ID` and `username`.

In my view, I can't access `ID` or `username`, it just drops out with an error    saying ID or username isn't part of model.

When I create the database, it clearly shows a picture of `ukcustomers` with a list of ID and username so it must be in there.

Comment: kindly please post the code for the view and the controller so we can see what is actually wrong, we have no way to tell if your code is wrong or the implementation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your entity/model/ViewModel. I think in your model you don't have Id and name properties.